# Other PC showing up in network activity under Security and svchost.exe (netsvcs)

Tags: windows, security

I'm mildly paranoid of people stealing information from my laptop, so I check network activity on occasion to see if there's anything out of the usual. Currently I'm at a relative's house and when I checked the activity, the name of their pc is showing up. The only processes being used with their pc name are System and svchost.exe. I was just curious if this could be any fishy business.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and define *checked the activity* and *showing up*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need any 3rd party software(firewall and etc), you already have all you need. When you connecting to any network, operation system asking you if you want to trust this network (Private or public network). If you choose to not share your computer resources, choose public profile, otherwise choose home/work(private) type of network. You can manage visibility/sharing options in profiles in the control panel->Network and Sharing Center where you can change "advanced sharing settings". Just turn off network discovery if you don't want to see other computer, you may want also to turn off file and printing sharing(both of these options already turned off if you choose "Public" profile for particular network)

If you want more fine grain settings to paranoid level, you can open embedded in windows firewal and disable "network discovery" for all type of profiles in inbound rules. More on this with pictures and in details you can find [on official OS maker site](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2010/12/06/disabling-network-discoverynetwork-resources/)

Such way you will keep your system lightweight without dependency on 3rd party software.

Comment: I appreciate the extra level of information, very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

The information you have provided only serves to demonstrate that your computer has "seen" another computer over a network and not so much communicated with it.

If you are truly security-conscious, install a personal firewall with a rich program control module (like GlassWire, Comodo Internet Security or ESET Internet Security) and learn how to use it in interactive mode. Doing so allows you to be in control of what comes in and what goes out. Otherwise, doing what you are doing right now only serves as entertainment and never yields an actual answer.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for, thanks for taking the time to answer!